# crossfilter reduce average mean display on bar chart p.value and p.key

Tags: reduce, dc.js, crossfilter, accessor

I am currently working on crossfilter example in order to produce funny benchmark with data available on equity stocks.
Here below is a sample of the data on a tsv file.

```
symbol  quarter grossprofit totalrevenue    ebitda  sector 
ABI.BR  Q1  7273000000  12239000000 3858000000  Ind
ABA.BR  Q2  7334000000  12201000000 3817000000  Ind
AA.BR   Q3  6318000000  10605000000 3097000000  Serv
A.BR    Q4  7229000000  11711000000 4185000000  Serv
ADC.PA  Q1  188000000   1297000000  110000000   Agri
SD.PA   Q2  188000000   1297000000  110000000   Agri
SQ.PA   Q3  247000000   1421000000  169000000   Customer
AC.PA   Q4  247000000   1421000000  169000000   Customer
GF.PA   Q1  3432000000  3432000000  671000000   Ind
RF.PA   Q2  3400000000  3400000000  631000000   Ind
ER.PA   Q3  3422000000  3422000000  713000000   Agri
TG.PA   Q4  3239000000  3239000000  349000000   Agri
```

The idea is to create an average value of the ebitda per sector, whatever the quarter or the symbol and to show results in a bar chart.

here below are the crossfilter code i use:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(mydata);
var all = ndx.groupAll();

var SectorDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.sector; });
var SectorDimGroup = SectorDim.group().reduce(
//add
function(p,v){
p.count++;
p.sec = v.sector;
p.sum += v['totalrevenue']/100000000;
p.avg = d3.round((p.sum/p.count),2);
return p;
},
//remove
function(p,v){
p.count--;
p.sec = v.sector;
p.sum -= v['totalrevenue']/100000000;
p.avg = d3.round((p.sum/p.count),2);
return p;
},
//init
function(p,v){
   return {count:0, sec:0,  avg:0, sum:0};
}
);

var result = SectorDimGroup.top(Infinity);
console.log("result variable");
console.log(result);
var minD = SectorDim.bottom(1)[0].sector;
console.log(minD);
var maxD = SectorDim.top(1)[0].sector;
console.log(maxD);
var mychart = dc.barChart("dc-bar-chart");


mychart.width(420)
.height(250)
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
.dimension(SectorDim)
.group(SectorDimGroup)
.valueAccessor(function (p) {
return p.value.avg;
})
//    .brushOn(false)
//    .elasticY(true)
   .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
```

From the grouping of crossfilter I get an object looking like {key:Serv, value{avg:123, sum:3456}}

I am trying to show on the x axis the industry sector (Serv, Agri, ...) and on the y axis, the average calculated for each sector (p.value.avg).

Unfortunately, it is not working at all.

1/ do you have any clue ? 
2/ a second step will be to group by quarter and to do the same exercise, if you have any way to manage a double "grouping" it would be great ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by not working. I think this will work best if you create a JSFiddle or Plunkr example showing the problem you're having. It will make it much easier for those of us here to see exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: here i added a jsfiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/e050110/h3jmd8nc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You simply had supplied invalid selectors to the chart constructors

Prefixing them with `#` seems to fix it:

```
    var mychart = dc.barChart("#dc-bar-chart");
    var V1Chart = dc.rowChart("#dc2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1hmb09e7/3/

(I also pointed the javascript libraries to public CDNs, since it looked like the original server wasn't working.)

It [would be nice](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/841) if dc.js pointed out that it was trying to create elements in the void.

You also might try minimizing your example next time, since this has nothing to do with what you thought you were asking about.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was pretty sure this was due to the calculation to have the average. Thanks a lot. Rgds